# Rails 4 - Ordering by something not stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, helper

I am using Rails 4. I have a `Room` model with `hour_price` `day_price` and `week_price` attributes.

On the index, users are able to enter different times and dates they would like to stay in a room. Based on these values, I have a helper method that then calculates the total price it would cost them using the price attributes mentioned above.

**My question is** what is the best way to sort through the `rooms` and order them least to greatest (in terms of price). Having a hard time figuring out the best way to do this, especially when considering the price value is calculated by a helper and isn't stored in the database.

Comment: How do you calculate the price in the helper? Are the calculations in the helper based on values from the database? Or could the values be stored in the database?

Comment: The price is calculated based on the times and dates entered by the user, then multiplied by either the `hour_price` `day_price` or `week_price` (which, yes, are being stored in the db). For example, if the user wants a 2 day room, the helper will multiply the `day_price * 2` @spickermann

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could load all of them and do an array sort as is [suggested here](http://awaxman11.github.io/blog/2013/10/11/sorting-a-rails-resource-based-on-a-calculated-value/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879040/how-can-i-sort-on-a-calculated-value). Though that would not scale well, but if you've already filtered by the rooms that are available this might be sufficient.

You might be able to push it back to the database by building a custom sql order by.

```
Rooms.order("(#{days} * day_price) asc")
```

Comment: Advanced option is a saving a function on database side and use it for sorting in queries. Pro tip for Postgres - add functional index with right direction of sorting for this query http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html